# VPN misconfiguration - help to find it:)

Tags: vpn, vps

Hi guys I wiould like to get some help configuring OpenVPN server. I use the custom VPS server and there deployed an VPN server. So After configuring it I still get some strange error.

Here's my server.conf:

```
port 443
proto tcp
dev tap
ca /ect/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC   # AES
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
log /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 7
```

And Here's my Client.ovpn. On client side I use Windows 7 system. (server's IP is hidden)

```
client
dev tap
proto tcp
remote 107.15x.1x4.17x 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca C:\\OVPN\\ca.crt
cert C:\\OVPN\\Vlad1.crt
key C:\\OVPN\\Vlad1.key
ns-cert-type server
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 7
```

And when I try to connect to my VPN server from windows 7 user, I get the following error, see the log(Server's ip is hidden):

```
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=160733 Current Parameter Settings:
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=160733   config = 'Vlad1.ovpn'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   mode = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   show_ciphers = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   show_digests = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   show_engines = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   genkey = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   key_pass_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   show_tls_ciphers = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733 Connection profiles [default]:
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   proto = tcp-client
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   local = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   local_port = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   remote = '107.15x.11x.172'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   remote_port = 443
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   remote_float = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   bind_defined = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   bind_local = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   connect_retry_seconds = 5
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   connect_timeout = 10
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   connect_retry_max = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   socks_proxy_server = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   socks_proxy_port = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   socks_proxy_retry = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   tun_mtu = 1500
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   tun_mtu_defined = ENABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   link_mtu = 1500
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   link_mtu_defined = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   tun_mtu_extra = 32
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   tun_mtu_extra_defined = ENABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   mtu_discover_type = -1
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   fragment = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   mssfix = 1450
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   explicit_exit_notification = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733 Connection profiles END
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   remote_random = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   ipchange = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   dev = 'tap'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   dev_type = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   dev_node = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   lladdr = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   topology = 1
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   tun_ipv6 = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   ifconfig_local = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   ifconfig_remote_netmask = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   ifconfig_noexec = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   ifconfig_nowarn = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   ifconfig_ipv6_local = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   ifconfig_ipv6_netbits = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   ifconfig_ipv6_remote = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   shaper = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   mtu_test = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   mlock = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   keepalive_ping = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   keepalive_timeout = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   inactivity_timeout = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   ping_send_timeout = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   ping_rec_timeout = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   ping_rec_timeout_action = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   ping_timer_remote = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   remap_sigusr1 = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   persist_tun = ENABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   persist_local_ip = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   persist_remote_ip = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   persist_key = ENABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   passtos = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   resolve_retry_seconds = 1000000000
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   username = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   groupname = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   chroot_dir = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   cd_dir = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   writepid = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   up_script = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   down_script = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   down_pre = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   up_restart = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   up_delay = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   daemon = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   inetd = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   log = ENABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   suppress_timestamps = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   nice = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   verbosity = 7
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   mute = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   gremlin = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   status_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   status_file_version = 1
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   status_file_update_freq = 60
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   occ = ENABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   rcvbuf = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   sndbuf = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   sockflags = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   fast_io = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   lzo = 7
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   route_script = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   route_default_gateway = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   route_default_metric = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   route_noexec = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   route_delay = 5
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   route_delay_window = 30
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   route_delay_defined = ENABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   route_nopull = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   route_gateway_via_dhcp = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   max_routes = 100
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   allow_pull_fqdn = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   management_addr = '127.0.0.1'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   management_port = 25340
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   management_user_pass = 'stdin'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   management_log_history_cache = 250
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   management_echo_buffer_size = 100
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   management_write_peer_info_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   management_client_user = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   management_client_group = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   management_flags = 6
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   shared_secret_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   key_direction = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   ciphername_defined = ENABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   ciphername = 'AES-128-CBC'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   authname_defined = ENABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   authname = 'SHA1'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   prng_hash = 'SHA1'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   prng_nonce_secret_len = 16
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   keysize = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   engine = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   replay = ENABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   mute_replay_warnings = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   replay_window = 64
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   replay_time = 15
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   packet_id_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   use_iv = ENABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   test_crypto = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   tls_server = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   tls_client = ENABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   key_method = 2
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   ca_file = 'C:\OVPN\ca.crt'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   ca_path = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   dh_file = 'C:\OVPN\dh2048.pem'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   cert_file = 'C:\OVPN\Vlad1.crt'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   extra_certs_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   priv_key_file = 'C:\OVPN\Vlad1.key'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   pkcs12_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   cryptoapi_cert = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   cipher_list = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   tls_verify = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   tls_export_cert = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   verify_x509_type = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   verify_x509_name = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   crl_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   ns_cert_type = 1
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=161733   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   remote_cert_eku = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   ssl_flags = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   tls_timeout = 2
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   renegotiate_bytes = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   renegotiate_packets = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   renegotiate_seconds = 3600
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   handshake_window = 60
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   transition_window = 3600
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   single_session = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   push_peer_info = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   tls_exit = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   tls_auth_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_pin_cache_period = -1
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_id = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   pkcs11_id_management = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   server_network = 0.0.0.0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=162733   server_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   server_network_ipv6 = ::
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   server_netbits_ipv6 = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   server_bridge_ip = 0.0.0.0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   server_bridge_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   server_bridge_pool_start = 0.0.0.0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   server_bridge_pool_end = 0.0.0.0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   ifconfig_pool_defined = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   ifconfig_pool_start = 0.0.0.0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   ifconfig_pool_end = 0.0.0.0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   ifconfig_pool_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   ifconfig_pool_persist_filename = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   ifconfig_pool_persist_refresh_freq = 600
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   ifconfig_ipv6_pool_defined = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   ifconfig_ipv6_pool_base = ::
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   ifconfig_ipv6_pool_netbits = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   n_bcast_buf = 256
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   tcp_queue_limit = 64
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   real_hash_size = 256
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   virtual_hash_size = 256
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   client_connect_script = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   learn_address_script = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   client_disconnect_script = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   client_config_dir = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   ccd_exclusive = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   tmp_dir = 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   push_ifconfig_defined = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   push_ifconfig_local = 0.0.0.0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   push_ifconfig_remote_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   push_ifconfig_ipv6_defined = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   push_ifconfig_ipv6_local = ::/0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   push_ifconfig_ipv6_remote = ::
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   enable_c2c = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   duplicate_cn = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   cf_max = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   cf_per = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   max_clients = 1024
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   max_routes_per_client = 256
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   auth_user_pass_verify_script = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   auth_user_pass_verify_script_via_file = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   client = ENABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   pull = ENABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   auth_user_pass_file = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   show_net_up = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   route_method = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   block_outside_dns = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   ip_win32_defined = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   ip_win32_type = 3
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   dhcp_masq_offset = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   dhcp_lease_time = 31536000
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   tap_sleep = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   dhcp_options = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   dhcp_renew = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   dhcp_pre_release = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   dhcp_release = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   domain = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   netbios_scope = '[UNDEF]'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   netbios_node_type = 0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733   disable_nbt = DISABLED
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733 OpenVPN 2.3.11 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [PKCS11] [IPv6] built on May 10 2016
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733 Windows version 6.1 (Windows 7) 64bit
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=163733 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016, LZO 2.09
Enter Management Password:
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=170733 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=171733 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=613759 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=714764 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=714764 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=799769 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=800769 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=934777 PRNG init md=SHA1 size=36
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=934777 crypto_adjust_frame_parameters: Adjusting frame parameters for crypto by zu bytes
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=934777 LZO compression initialized
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=934777 PID packet_id_init tcp_mode=1 seq_backtrack=64 time_backtrack=15
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=934777 PID packet_id_init tcp_mode=1 seq_backtrack=64 time_backtrack=15
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=934777 PID packet_id_init tcp_mode=1 seq_backtrack=64 time_backtrack=15
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=934777 PID packet_id_init tcp_mode=1 seq_backtrack=64 time_backtrack=15
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=934777 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1592 D:1210 EF:40 EB:0 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=934777 MTU DYNAMIC mtu=1450, flags=2, 1592 -> 1450
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=934777 Socket Buffers: R=[8192->8192] S=[8192->8192]
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=934777 RESOLVE_REMOTE flags=0x0101 phase=1 rrs=0 sig=-1 status=0
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=934777 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1592 D:1450 EF:60 EB:143 ET:32 EL:3 AF:3/1 ]
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=934777 Local Options String: 'V4,dev-type tap,link-mtu 1592,tun-mtu 1532,proto TCPv4_CLIENT,comp-lzo,cipher AES-128-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-client'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=934777 Expected Remote Options String: 'V4,dev-type tap,link-mtu 1592,tun-mtu 1532,proto TCPv4_SERVER,comp-lzo,cipher AES-128-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-server'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=934777 Local Options hash (VER=V4): '39ac68d4'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=934777 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): 'de0ebdfe'
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=934777 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]107.15x.11x.172:443 [nonblock]
Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=934777 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1465048828,TCP_CONNECT,,,
Sat Jun 04 17:00:38 2016 us=936349 TCP: connect to [AF_INET]107.15x.11x.172:443 failed, will try again in 5 seconds: Connection timed out (WSAETIMEDOUT)
Sat Jun 04 17:00:40 2016 us=936463 PID packet_id_free
Sat Jun 04 17:00:40 2016 us=936463 PID packet_id_free
Sat Jun 04 17:00:40 2016 us=936463 PID packet_id_free
Sat Jun 04 17:00:40 2016 us=936463 PID packet_id_free
Sat Jun 04 17:00:40 2016 us=936463 PID packet_id_free
Sat Jun 04 17:00:40 2016 us=936463 PID packet_id_free
Sat Jun 04 17:00:40 2016 us=936463 PID packet_id_free
Sat Jun 04 17:00:40 2016 us=936463 PID packet_id_free
Sat Jun 04 17:00:40 2016 us=936463 PID packet_id_free
Sat Jun 04 17:00:40 2016 us=936463 SIGTERM[hard,init_instance] received, process exiting
Sat Jun 04 17:00:40 2016 us=936463 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1465048840,EXITING,init_instance,,
Sat Jun 04 17:00:40 2016 us=936463 PKCS#11: Terminating openssl
Sat Jun 04 17:00:40 2016 us=936463 PKCS#11: Removing providers
Sat Jun 04 17:00:40 2016 us=936463 PKCS#11: Releasing sessions
Sat Jun 04 17:00:40 2016 us=937463 PKCS#11: Terminating slotevent
Sat Jun 04 17:00:40 2016 us=937463 PKCS#11: Marking as uninitialized
Sat Jun 04 17:00:40 2016 us=937463 Closing Win32 semaphore 'openvpn_netcmd'
```

So here I'm just guessing what's wrong with this whole config?

The only one suggestion that I have about it - it's a very big MTU, which makes the connection imposssible. I tried to ping from windows' cmd my server with the following mtu command:

ping -n 1 -l 1500 -f www.example.com

The output of 1500mtu - the packet is lost

The output of 1430mtu - the packet was received.

I don't know - maybe it's the only one reason why VPN server doesn't work?

Big thanks to this community in advance who can help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=934777 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]107.15x.11x.172:443 [nonblock]
    Sat Jun 04 17:00:28 2016 us=934777 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1465048828,TCP_CONNECT,,,
    Sat Jun 04 17:00:38 2016 us=936349 TCP: connect to [AF_INET]107.15x.11x.172:443 failed, will try again in 5 seconds: Connection timed out (WSAETIMEDOUT)
```

Check connectivity:

`telnet 107.15x.11x.172 443`

Comment: Hi, I checked the connectivity, and unfortunatelly it doesn't work at all... what's the next step?

Comment: Fix it. Check firewalls all the way along from client to server.

Comment: I can't pretty much understand how to do it... can you explain me please in detail? Im totally new to this

Comment: @woozman:

This is large theme, not to be explained in few lines. Good poinht to start is here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50098/linux-network-troubleshooting-and-debugging And try googling for "linux ip connectivity troubleshooting".